# Using Jersey in Spring Boot for file upload getting 400 Bad Request

Tags: spring-boot, jersey

I have tried a large number of examples for doing file upload with jersey. I can get it to work with pure Spring using @RequestMapping, ResponseEntity instead of `@Path`  etc.  But I want to use jersey, as all of my other endpoints are handled by jersey.

UPDATE: I feel that I'm unable to pass an form data, file or text. Even a single FormDataParam of `@FormDataParam("directory") String directory` gives the bad request

I have the following class

```
@Component
@Path("/v1.0")
public class FileOperationsResource  {

    private ConfigurationReader mConfigReader;

    @Autowired
    public FileOperationsResource(ConfigurationReader configurationReader) {
        mConfigReader = configurationReader;
    }

   @POST
   @Path("/file/upload")
   @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
   public Response uploadFile(@QueryParam("dir") String directory,
                              @FormDataParam("file") InputStream file,
                              @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDisposition) {
```

I have added the following line to my ResourceConfig

```
register(MultiPartFeature.class);
```

I have added the following maven dependency, but have not added a version as my understanding is that it will automatically pull the version that works with my version of spring, and I have found newer versions no longer allow me to add register in `ResourceConfig` as `MultiPartFeature` is missing.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When I make the following call, I get a 400 Bad Request. I feel like I must be making the call wrong, or have failed to wire something else in.  Any help would be appreciated.

Response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-04-20T15:51:01.790+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Bad Request",
    "path": "/api/v1.0/file/upload"
}
```

I've made the call with Postman and using forms, as well as curl with the following call

```
curl --verbose --form file=@"settings.xml" http://localhost:8080/api/v1.0/file/upload?dir=MyDir
```

Comment: `dir` should be a query param, but you're trying to send it as a form param in your request. Query param should go at the end of the URL. `"<url>?dir=myapps"`. Maybe that's the problem. If you want to add it as a form param, then make the parameter `@FormDataParam("dir")`

Comment: I've tried it that way, I think the CURL shows it, the update example was to state that I can't seem to pass any type of FormData

Comment: Everything looks good. I can't reproduce the problem. Must be something you're not showing us. Not sure what it could be.

Comment: Do you have a sample project or something you tried this with?  I'm using SpringBoot, is there a version issue?

Comment: As an example if I try to mimick the example here
https://bytefish.de/blog/file_upload_api_jersey/

I can't register MultiPartFeature in my ResouceConfig, the import does not exist.  But if i do not specify a version for jersey-media-multipart in the POM, I'm fine

Comment: here you go https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-boot-upload-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your `spring.jersey.type` set to in `application.properties`?  I have file upload working with Jersey and Boot, I believe this is what you need:

```
# JERSEY
spring.jersey.type=servlet
spring.jersey.servlet.load-on-startup=1
```

For example purposes, here's my endpoint:

```
@POST
@Path("/file/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
                           @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDisposition) {

    String fileName = fileDisposition.getFileName();
    StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder();
    int read = 0;
    int totalBytesRead = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    try {
        while ((read = fileInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            ...save file...
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        mLogger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this answer solves the problem of 400, as that's the problem statement in the post.

Comment: I don't fully understand how this works, but it does.  I'm wondering if it's not finding some different way to re-direct the call?  As soon as I changed the two configs, it worked.

Comment: [Here is the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50423639/2587435). It's because of configuring Jersey as a filter (instead of the default servlet), which sometimes is necessary.

Comment: How was this marked a duplicate, when this question was asked before the other one it's a duplicate of?